# Why is my HTML file only sometimes loading correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a small webpage using raw HTML/javascript. Here is the entire current content of my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
        <style>
        * {
           margin: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
        }

        div.banner-light {
            background-color:#9090d0;
            position: absolute;
            left:0px;
        }

        div.banner-dark {
            background-color:#8080e0;
            position: absolute;
            left:0px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="javascript:onLoadBody()">

    <script>
        function onLoadBody() {
            var curHeight = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
                document.getElementById("stat" + i.toString()).style.top = curHeight.toString() + "px";
                document.getElementById("stat" + i.toString()).style.width = (screen.availWidth * 0.15).toString() + "px";
                document.getElementById("stat" + i.toString()).style.height = ((window.innerHeight - curHeight) / (25 - i)).toString() + "px";

                curHeight += ((window.innerHeight - curHeight) / (25 - i));
            }
        }

        function clickDiv(id) {
            document.getElementById("stat" + id).innerHTML = "Clicked";
        }
    </script>

    <div id='stat1' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(1)"><center>1</center></div>
    <div id='stat2' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(2)"><center>2</center></div>
    <div id='stat3' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(3)"><center>3</center></div>
    <div id='stat4' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(4)"><center>4</center></div>
    <div id='stat5' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(5)"><center>5</center></div>
    <div id='stat6' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(6)"><center>6</center></div>
    <div id='stat7' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(7)"><center>7</center></div>
    <div id='stat8' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(8)"><center>8</center></div>
    <div id='stat9' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(9)"><center>9</center></div>
    <div id='stat10' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(10)"><center>10</center></div>
    <div id='stat11' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(11)"><center>11</center></div>
    <div id='stat12' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(12)"><center>12</center></div>
    <div id='stat13' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(13)"><center>13</center></div>
    <div id='stat14' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(14)"><center>14</center></div>
    <div id='stat15' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(15)"><center>15</center></div>
    <div id='stat16' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(16)"><center>16</center></div>
    <div id='stat17' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(17)"><center>17</center></div>
    <div id='stat18' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(18)"><center>18</center></div>
    <div id='stat19' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(19)"><center>19</center></div>
    <div id='stat20' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(20)"><center>20</center></div>
    <div id='stat21' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(21)"><center>21</center></div>
    <div id='stat22' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(22)"><center>22</center></div>
    <div id='stat23' class="banner-light" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(23)"><center>23</center></div>
    <div id='stat24' class="banner-dark" onclick="javascript:clickDiv(24)"><center>24</center></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Strangely, when I try to view this file in a browser, it will sometimes load exactly as I want - the numbers 1 through 24 down the left side the page with an alternating background. But, about 4 times out of 5, all the numbers will gather in the top-left in a way that indicates an error (try it for yourself).

The strange thing is that you can open this exact file 10 times without editing it at all, and it will work correctly in only a couple of instances. I didn't even think this was possible, but it certainly goes against everything I know as a programmer. If you know of anything that can cause this please let me know. Incidentally please excuse anything I may have done poorly as I'm fairly new and teaching myself this.

**Edit: After messing around with some suggested solutions about the order of my HTML, JS and CSS, I realised how convoluted my above code is: instead of using onload, I've just set div's style width and height to percentages. Thanks anyway everyone!**

Comment: use $(document).ready(function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not go about things the way you do. Having elements absolute places them on the screen, but they physically do not take the space. It is like throwing a cube in a glass of water. The level of the water will rise. When the cube is "absolute" it will not so that. So you will have to make the divs relative and then they will just stack on top of each other the way you want.

```
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    div {
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    div.banner-light {
        background-color: #9090d0;
        left: 0px;
    }
    div.banner-dark {
        background-color: #8080e0;
        left: 0px;
    }


  window.onload = function () {


      var curHeight = window.innerHeight;
      console.log(curHeight);
      for (var i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
          document.getElementById("stat" + i.toString()).style.width = (screen.availWidth * 0.15).toString() + "px";
          document.getElementById("stat" + i.toString()).style.height = (curHeight / (25 - 1)).toString() + "px";

      }

  }

  function clickDiv(id) {
      document.getElementById("stat" + id).innerHTML = "Clicked";
  }
```

Make your divs relative and only control their width.

**Edit - Make the height adapt to the screen height:**

In order to make the height of the divs to adapt to the screen height, you have your math a little wrong. You should read the height of the window and then divide it by 24.

I have adapted the above code as well as the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/Ap4Sq/5/

Please note that you will have problems with people resizing the window. Also the font size does not adapt. So if this solution is really useful is up to you.
Here is also a fiddle that addresses the resizing.

Fiddle with resizing: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/Ap4Sq/6/

Also note that you can get things smarter with giving your divs a similar class. You can add more classes than just one. ie `<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>`

And one that even adapts the font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/Ap4Sq/8/

Comment: Hmm, well that has fixed the issue, but I wanted the banners to stretch to the full height of the user's screen rather than being a fixed height. Changing their height in the JS causes the random-failure problem to come back. I'll mess around with it a bit more.

Comment: I have edited the answer with new fiddles. Hope that will help you better understand things.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `script` tag (and contents) to **below** all your divs, right before the end of your `body` tag. That way you ensure that the DOM elements are created when calling your functions. It seems like something could definitely be going on there. You should also look into removing your inline event definitions.

Here's a [jsfiddle example with script defined at the bottom of the body](http://jsfiddle.net/cRNVz/)

Here's a [jsfiddle example onLoad](http://jsfiddle.net/cRNVz/1/)

Comment: Good idea, but that hasn't made a difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `script` tag into the `head` then? So it's available when it's called by the `body`? I've changed the code a bit as a suggestion and put it into a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cRNVz/2/